# git: How do I get rid of "warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF" without disabling safecrlf?

Tags: git

I'm new to git, and I've read a lot about line endings and
how git treats them. I'm on Windows by the way. I have made
a `.gitattributes` file and set for example *.txt to text.
When I commit a .txt file, I get the warning:

> warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in whatever.txt

But I know that. I don't need that warning. Replacing line
endings in text files is what I want.

Now, setting `safecrlf` to false makes the warning
disappear, but the manual for `safecrlf` reads:

> If true, makes git check if converting CRLF is reversible
>   when end-of-line conversion is active. Git will verify if
>   a command modifies a file in the work tree either directly
>   or indirectly. For example, committing a file followed by
>   checking out the same file should yield the original file
>   in the work tree. If this is not the case for the current
>   setting of core.autocrlf, git will reject the file.

From that, `safecrlf` seems like a good idea to have.
However, I don't understand why setting `safecrlf` to true
gives me warnings about my text files; it seems to me that
those are different issues -- the warning on text files and
the checking if reversible. Indeed, git does not reject my
file.

Can I get rid of the warnings for text files, and still have
`safecrlf` set? Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Why wasn't the file being converted already a Window's style file?  I feel this warning is good in that git is telling you it modified the file in some way.  The real solution is not have the file in a state where git has to modify it.  If you cloned from a central repository, you might be doing something dangerous to others.

Comment: cforbish I think it was a Windows style file. It has CRLF in it, and it's gonna get committed with LF endings instead. But I knew that.

Comment: oskarkv sorry for the misunderstanding.  Do you happen to use vim/gvim?  If so you can make the file a Linux style file with `:set ff=unix`, to avoid the warning.  This actually modifies the file so you would have to `:w`.

Comment: I find a better solution is to always keep line-endings as-is, and use [.editorconfig](http://editorconfig.org/) to keep things consistent... Most IDEs on Windows and Mac can use either line ending in reality (as long as you make sure everyone has the [plugin](http://editorconfig.org/#download) installed).

Answer (score 16):

As far as I can tell, setting `core.safecrlf` to `false` is the **only** way to turn off that warning.

`safecrlf` is generally not necessary if your attributes are set correctly. The point of `safecrlf` is to prevent normalization in a file that is *supposed to* have mixed (or non-LF) line endings in the repository. It's really only useful in combination with `core.autocrlf` (to make sure that its automatic guesses can't destroy anything), and if you're setting your own attributes via `.gitattributes` it should be okay to turn all that off.

Answer (score 11):

In your `.gitattributes` you can:

```
# normalize text files to use lf
text eol=lf

# except these which we want crlf
*.txt eol=crlf
```

Comment: You can also do fun things with how diffs are done, e.g. `*.cs eol=crlf diff=csharp`

Comment: That does not answer my question.

Answer (score 7):

The short answer to your question is NO.

Because, basically, core.safecrlf setting controls "warning level":

- false - proceed without warning
- warn - proceed with warning
- true - don't proceed

So, you have to choose option that suits you the most.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
$ git config core.autocrlf false
```