# Recurring npm warning in Jade displayed upon running `git add .` in a node + express directory

Tags: node.js, git, pug

I started a new Express directory and ran `git add .` to add it to source control.  When I did, I go the following errors:

```
$ express -c stylus
$ sudo npm install -d
$ git init
$ git add .
warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in node_modules/jade/node_modules/constantinople/.gitattributes.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in node_modules/jade/node_modules/constantinople/.npmignore.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in node_modules/jade/node_modules/constantinople/.travis.yml.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in node_modules/jade/node_modules/constantinople/LICENSE.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in node_modules/jade/node_modules/constantinople/README.md.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in node_modules/jade/node_modules/constantinople/index.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in node_modules/jade/node_modules/constantinople/node_modules/uglify-js/node_modules/uglify-to-browserify/.npmignore.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in node_modules/jade/node_modules/constantinople/node_modules/uglify-js/node_modules/uglify-to-browserify/.travis.yml.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in node_modules/jade/node_modules/constantinople/node_modules/uglify-js/node_modules/uglify-to-browserify/LICENSE.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in node_modules/jade/node_modules/constantinople/node_modules/uglify-js/node_modules/uglify-to-browserify/README.md.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in node_modules/jade/node_modules/constantinople/node_modules/uglify-js/node_modules/uglify-to-browserify/index.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in node_modules/jade/node_modules/constantinople/node_modules/uglify-js/node_modules/uglify-to-browserify/test/index.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in node_modules/jade/node_modules/constantinople/test/index.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
```

How can I suppress these?  Should I fix the problem or ignore it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [git replacing LF with CRLF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967370/git-replacing-lf-with-crlf)

Comment: Also [How do I get rid of “warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF” without disabling safecrlf?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16873848/git-how-do-i-get-rid-of-warning-crlf-will-be-replaced-by-lf-without-disablin)

Comment: @JonathanLonowski, I tried running `$ git config --global core.autocrlf input` on my Mac OSX and repeated the above steps.  I still got the same warnings.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski, as for the second link, I appreciate being schooled on git's use of CRLF and LF but I asked this question to document these errors' presence in `Jade`.  It's the only `node.js` model throwing it so I'm looking for a Jade-specific answer.  Are you suggesting StackOverflow is not the right venue for this request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This cannot solve the problem, but it looks like the Jade developers will not fix this issue - https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/issues/1128

If they wanted to, they could run `$ git config --global core.autocrlf input` locally to stop the error from being produced.