# Why am I STILL getting warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF when autocrlf is true?

Tags: windows, git

We're using Windows, we've set up our git to checkout Windows-style (CRLF) and commit Unix-style (LF), any code auto-generated from various programs or editors already creates LF endings, so everything's compatible except whenever I stash I get the same warning even though I've already set autocrlf to true for each repo and globally:

`git stash`
`warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF`

`git config core.autocrlf`
true

`git config --global core.autocrlf`
true

I just read something about core.safecrlf but I'm not sure it applies to this issue (but the setting is blank, as in false).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git: How do I get rid of "warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF" without disabling safecrlf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16873848/git-how-do-i-get-rid-of-warning-crlf-will-be-replaced-by-lf-without-disablin)

Comment: The top answer says "setting core.safecrlf to false is the only way to turn off that warning", but it's already blank, which means false as far as I know, because it's definitely not 'true'.

Comment: `core.safecrlf` defaults to `warn` behavior if unset when `core.autocrlf` is set to `true`. You need to explicitly set it to `false` to get rid of the warning.